# Extraction of primary key of event-hub Microsoft-azure from " Get-AzureRmEventHubKey " command power-shell

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-eventhub

I want to take **primary key** from the output of "Get-AzureRmEventHubKey" and store it **in a variable**, how can I do that through powershell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try the following PowerShell cmdlet to extract primary key from even-hub:

```
$PrimaryKey = Get-AzureRmEventHubKey -ResourceGroupName myResourceGroup -NamespaceName namespace_name -Name RootManageSharedAccessKey |Select -ExpandProperty "PrimaryKey"
```

Comment: Executed successfully

Comment: If this answers your query, do click “Mark as Answer” and Up-Vote for the same.